# insert into table using VALUES(1,2...) or select 1,2

Tags: sql-server

Which of the following queries is more efficient?

```
DECLARE @i int 

SET @i = 1 

WHILE (@i < 40) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table (number) 
    VALUES (@i) 

    SET @i = @i + 1 
END
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table (number) 
    SELECT n 
    FROM anothertable 
    WHERE n <= @i
```

`anothertable` is a table with a column `n` with numbers from 1..100.

Please help

Comment: Set-based approaches are almost always faster than anything loop-based simply because the T-SQL parser/compiler is so slow, plus the overhead of per-row transactions if you don't do it all in one. But as always with questions of "which is faster" -- just *test*, it's simple enough in this case.

Comment: the former is like programming and the latter is query. using the latter should be much faster.However, that should be determined from execution plan.

Comment: Learning to design and write set-based solutions will serve you much more that optimizing a 40 row insert (which seems an odd thing to do as presented).

Comment: Most RDBMS are optimized to perform better with set based actions *(like an insert from select)* compared to procedural logic.  Sql Server won't be the exception.

Comment: Use execution plan.

Comment: Second one is more efficient, but you could improve it by doing `SELECT TOP (@i)`. See also [Number series generator challenge solutions](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) by Itzik Ben-Gan for much better solutions, some of which don't involve any table at all